# Installed Ubuntu deleted it, now no OS working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I was trying to switch to Linux from Windows system. I installed Ubuntu for dual boot but don't know what went wrong and when it asked to restart after installation then again it started showing the dashboard for new installation. Then I removed the pendrive and it started showing that 'no bootable device'. After that I went in the installation menu of Ubuntu and deleted all the 3 paths. I am trying to get back my windows as I have lots of data in that. Please help!!!

Comment: **First** of all you could boot up again from the pen drive and use live session of Ubuntu in order to **backup your important data** from any partition. Edit your question to explain exactly what you want: do you want to keep a dual boot or just Ubuntu? If you don't need Windows why do you say `I am trying to get back my windows as I have lots of data in that`? Or do you want just Ubuntu but with the former Windows partition available? How have you installed Ubuntu? Have you manually created more partitions ? Please clarify. Add info on what Ubuntu version you use.

Comment: And what does it mean `I went in the installation menu of Ubuntu and deleted all the 3 paths`? I hope you don't mean "partitions".

Comment: In order to investigate partitions, boot in the live session and post the results of `sudo fdisk -l` here.